# Magento: query through customer address with custom field

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've added a custom filed to the customer addresses, but I don't know how to query using this field.

I'm executing the following piece of code:

> $collection =    Mage::getModel('customer/address')
>       ->getCollection()
>       ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_field')
>       ->addFieldToFilter('custom_field', '1'); 
>   echo var_dump($collection);

But I'm facing this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
>   app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

My question is: how can I query through this field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests, I could solve the problem. Here's the code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_field', 1)
                ->getItems();
echo print_r($collection, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')

Instead of

> Mage::getModel('customer/address') ->getCollection()

See /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_field') 
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_field', '1')
                   ->getItems();
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but it didn't work :/ - I can execute the first line withouth errors but when I try adding the #2 or 3# lines, the errror I mentioned happen again. Any other idea?